# Can we store values to a null location?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, c++14

So I was working with linked lists and it occurred to me if we could store values to an object to a null location.

Also, if we cannot store values to a null location, why is that?(because in c++ when we assign 0 to a pointer, it gets pointed to null.)

Comment: You could try it. Hint: it causes a crash.

Comment: That memory location is readonly.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat There are small and tiny systems without memory-protection or paging. Also, with optimizing compilers there is no guarantee the access is even attempted. It might just get pruned.

Comment: Is this a purely theoretical question or you have the actual need to do that?

Comment: `void (*ptr)() = 0; ptr();` – saw that code already to reset a micro-controller – wouldn't consider it clean, but was vendor's own code... On the other hand, if we consider such a µC, writing to address 0 might work while system is running but most likely is absolutely fatal on next start or reset!

Comment: Depends on the platform.  In embedded systems, the address 0x0000 may be a valid memory location.   You may need permission from the Kernel/OS depending on the OS you are using.  Historically, the value 0 has been an indicator of null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Sloppy speaking, `NULL` or `nullptr` is a placeholder value for pointers that point nowhere. You cannot store a value nowhere. If you try something like this:

```
int* p = nullptr;
*p = 5;
```

Your program will very likely crash (no guarantee, in fact it is undefined what happens if you do so).

An `int*` does not store an `int`. It can point to an `int` that holds a value. To store an `int` you need an `int` object somewhere not just a pointer:

```
int x = 0;
int* p = &x;
*p = 42;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can we store values to a null location?

You can only store values into objects. Objects can only be created into allocated memory. It is not possible to arbitrarily specify the address of memory to allocate.

I suppose that in theory, the language implementation maybe could choose to store an object of static storage duration into the address that represents null pointer value. In such case, an object would be stored in "null location". This would not be very typical.